# Is $\{a,b,c\}^* \setminus \{a^nb^mc^k \mid n \leq m \leq k\}$ context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

i have seen this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68423/context-freeness-of-anbmck-mid-n-leq-m-leq-k-and-its-complement) where someone was asking if $\{a,b,c\}^* \setminus \{a^nb^mc^k \mid n \leq m \leq k\}$ is context free.

Then there was an [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/68429/136833) that says that it is context free because:

The language, in turn, is context-free. This is because we can write it as a union of context-free languages:

- Words not of the form $a^*c^*b^*$
- Words of the form $a^nb^mc^k$ where >
- Words of the form $a^nb^mc^k$ where >.

So my question is, why can't i take the language $\{a^nb^nc^k | n > m > k\}$?

Isn't that also the complement of the language?

If so, that would be pumpable with the word z = $a^{n+2}b^{n+1}c^n$ right?

I am a little bit confused and feel like i missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid n>m>k\}$ is not the complement of $\{a^nb^mc^k\mid n\le m\le k\}$, for two reasons.

(1) The negation of the logical statement "$P\land Q$" is not "$\lnot P\land \lnot Q$", it is "$\lnot P\lor \lnot Q$".

(2) The original language consists of only strings in the language $a^*b^*c^*$, so the complement must include all strings where the order of symbols is not alphabetical.

As a consequence the complement of "$n\le m\le k$" is then the union of three languages "$n>m$", "$m>k$", "not alphabetical", each of which is context-free. Occasionally the "not alphabetical" part $\{a,b,c\}^*\setminus a^*b^*c^*$ is overlooked, but as that is a regular language it is the least problematic part.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

```
Isn't that also the complement of the language?
```

Here *that* refers to $L' = \{a^n b^m c^k \mid n > m > k\}$ but I'm not sure what *the language* refers to. It could be $L=\{a^n b^m c^k \mid n \le m \le k\}$ or $L'' = \{a,b,c\}^* \setminus L$.
In any case:

- $L'$ is not the complement of $L$. As (one of the many possible choices for a) witness, notice that $b$ belongs to neither $L$ nor $L'$.
- $L'$ is not the complement of $L''$. A witness is $aab$ since it belongs to both $L'$ and $L''$.